# CakePHP 2.1 excel file export and import to database

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, cakephp-2.1, import-from-excel

I am using cakephp 2.1 and developing an application which needed more data. I want to use excel file for import and export. Please suggest me some solutions to get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Microsoft's "CSV for Excel"](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010099725.aspx) for importing data. It's the same as a generic CSV but then with different delimiters. If you want to create complex Excel sheets, then you should use something like [PHPExcell](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).

The -1 on your question is for asking it wrongly. A quick Google Search would yield the same result as me typing this in...